# Is it good practice to declare derivate classes in the same C++ header?

Tags: c++, header-files, derived-class, organization

I'm declaring a pure virtual class that will provide a unified interface for a handful of derived classes. My instinctual way to organize this would be to create a base folder with the header for the base class (e.g `lib/Base.h`)  and then create subfolders for the header + source file of the derived classes (so `lib/implA/ImplA.h`,`lib/implA/ImplA.cpp` and so forth). This keeps the files short, but feels cluttered.

Would it be considered good practice to gather the definitions of the derived classes in the header `lib/Base.h` and keep the various implementations in the same folder?

Comment: When someone `#include "lib/Base.h"`, he/she will know all subclasses and their definitions. Do you want that?

Comment: If the header contains everything, I would call it `lib.h` rather than `Base.h`. It can be ok if the header is still of reasonable size, and most users need several derived classes.

Comment: Can this question be improved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two-file folders (like `lib/implA/ImplA.h`, `lib/implA/ImplA.cpp`) are unnecessary, for small projects people usually just put everything in `lib/`. If `lib/` becomes too cluttered, put this whole hierarchy in `lib/my_hierarchy/Base.h`, `lib/my_hierarchy/ImplA.cpp`, etc. Maybe extract a logical subsystem instead of a hierarchy. Just keep reasonable folder sizes and some organized structure.

As for putting multiple declarations in the same header, it's your design choice. As far as I know, there's no single "best practice" in C++ regarding this. C++ doesn't enforce one class per file, like Java does. However, including a lot of classes in a single header means slightly longer compilation times for users, because that long header needs to be parsed in every `.cpp` file where it's `#include`d. Usually people try to keep their headers minimal, but also provide a convenience "aggregate" header that includes all other headers (like `bits/stdc++.h` for the standard library). In your case, that would be:

```
// lib/lib.h

#include "my_hierarchy/Base.h"
#include "my_hierarchy/ImplA.h"
// etc.
```

So that users who don't mind longer compilation times can just `#include <lib/lib.h>` and have everything, while others can `#include` only classes they need.

Answer (score 2):

It is neither good nor bad. What matters is what you want to present as an API, that is what a user or your classes will have to write in their own sources. `#include "lib/implA/ImplA.h"` uses 2 directory level which is not very common while not being too much either IMHO. It can makes sense if a single application will seldom use more than one implementation.

For the way you want to organize your headers and translation units, it is really a question of having *reasonable* sizes. And the magnitude order may vary between teams...